# How to add fo:root child elements in xml using jaxb annotations

Tags: java, jaxb, xsl-fo, apache-fop

i am trying to create an xml file which would be compatibe with the tags mentioned in my .xsl file in order to create pdf docs using apache fo docs

Below is my code

**welcome_template.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform <http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform> "
        xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format <http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format> "
        version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4">
                    <fo:region-body margin="1in"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <fo:block font-size="12pt" font-family="Arial" text-align="start">
                    <xsl:text>Hi </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="userDTO/firstName"/>
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="userDTO/lastName"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <fo:block/>
                    <fo:block font-size="12pt" font-family="Arial" text-align="start">
                    <xsl:text>Thank you for opening an account with ICICI bank.</xsl:text>
                    <fo:block/>
                    <fo:block font-size="12pt" font-family="Arial" text-align="start">
                    <xsl:text>Your registered email id with us is: </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="userDTO/emailId"/>
                    <fo:block/>
                    <fo:block font-size="12pt" font-family="Arial" text-align="start">
                        <xsl:text>Your mobile number is: </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="userDTO/contactNumber"/>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**UserDTO.java**

```
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;


@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name="fo:root")
public class UserDTO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String emailId;
    private String contactNumber;

}
```

When i run my application i get following error

```
org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:root" is missing child elements. Required content model: (layout-master-set, declarations?, bookmark-tree?, (page-sequence|fox:external-document)+) (See position 2:56)
    at org.apache.fop.events.ValidationExceptionFactory.createException(ValidationExceptionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.fop.events.EventExceptionManager.throwException(EventExceptionManager.java:58)
    at org.apache.fop.events.DefaultEventBroadcaster$1.invoke(DefaultEventBroadcaster.java:173)
```

What jaxb annotation needs to be added in **UserDTO.java** in order to match it with **welcome_template.xsl** file.

Any inputs will be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

JAXB annotations are used to map Java classes to XML and back again. However, your welcome_template.xsl isn't a mapping of the UserDTO Java class. It is an XSL transformation (XSLT) that is used to transform XML documents into other formats.

If you want to transform 'UserDTO' to xml, you have to annotate your 'UserDTO' Java class to map it to XML

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "userDTO")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class UserDTO {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@XmlAttribute
private int id;

@XmlElement
private String firstName;
.
.
.
```

Note that I changed the xmlRootElement name to userDTO class because your xml will represent UserDTO.

Then, you can feed this XML into XSLT to generate your PDF.

Comment: i get below error if i do that

org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: First element must be the fo:root formatting object. Found (Namespace URI: "", Local Name: "userDTO") instead. Please make sure you're producing a valid XSL-FO document.